# Unique generated strings in Laravel 5 using MySQL

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

For my appointment table, I'm letting MySQL increment my id (primary key) for each new row. My application uses this appointment id in my routes, which is fine. But in order to be able to reference a specific appointment id without "showing" the id itself (in a link sent by email for example), I would like for my appointment table to have a column which contains a string that is unique to this specific appointment (but not part of the primary key).

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('appointments', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->dateTime('appointment_at');

        $table->string('my_unique_key')->unique(); --> Want unique generated string

        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I've read about UUID, Laravel's str_random() and md5. Of course str_random and md5 would not generate a unique string that I can use when inserting a new row to my appointment table.

So I guess would need to have retry logic when inserting to verify that my string is unique, unless MySQL can do that? I'm afraid retry logic would create overhead and lower the performance of my app if have a lot of users adding appointments at the same time.

Would an MD5 of my created_at timestamp be close to unique? What if I concatenate the values of two variables (ex: created_at and appointment_at) and then do a MD5, would that do the trick?

What would be the syntax for retry logic in here?

```
public function store(AppointmentsRequest $request)
{
    $appointment = Appointment::create(Request::all());

    return redirect('appointments/'.$appointment->id );
}
```

Comment: UUIDs, if set up properly and depending on the version, *would* be unique. That's the definition, after all ;)

Comment: I think a collision in MD5 would be pretty rare, so I don't think the performance hit would be noticeable.

Comment: @StuartWagner Fixed my sentence :) Would you know of a simple solution to have MySQL generate UUID on my column? I would I define that using Laravel's Eloquent?

Comment: @user3489502 I would recommend this: https://github.com/ramsey/uuid

Comment: I'm trying to understand how it works. Does Eloquent (or Laravel function) first need to do a manual select by trying to find out if the UUID generated string exists before it writes the new record to the table? If so, why would UUID be a better solution compared to any other string generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Generate an MD5 hash from a value (or values) unique to the row for which you're generating the token. I wouldn't worry too much about collisions; it's extremely unlikely.

You can use an MD5 hash of a value (or a concatenated set of values) that's unique to the row.

Here's the thing about MD5: it is possible to have the same hash for two different values. This is called a collision. **But**... the MD5 hash is 128 bits long. That means there are 2^128 possible values for the hash. So while a collision is possible, it is highly unlikely.

If you're want to use an MD5 hash and you're really concerned about collisions between your values, you will need to write some retry logic. But bear in mind that you will probably never need to retry. I would not worry about performance.

There are a couple of ways to implement this:

- It is possible to implement this on the MySQL server, by using a stored procedure to insert the value. The stored procedure could check for a unique token at insert time & generate a new one accordingly.
- You could implement it as a unique index on the column and catch any errors that arise on insert and retry.

You also need to consider how you're using the value. You mention using it as a token in an email - maybe you can expire the value after it's used or after a certain period. That would reduce the total number of tokens needed at any given time, which would reduce the (already miniscule) chance of a collision even further.

Comment: thanks. Oh I see, retry on collisions only, not a select before each update. Do you know of any way to automatically save a value in md5 in Laravel 5?